# Textbox displayed instead of checkbox

Tags: html, forms, hosting

I have very unusual problem. I've created an HTML form with all types of inputs.

Then I put it on a server and what happened took me to the ground literally. All my checkboxes turned into textboxes. The code I put on my website has checkboxes in it, but when I use firebug it says it has textboxes there.

-HTML code is valid:

```
<input name="ksh" type="checkbox" id="ksh" />
```

I tried on a different server, it works fine there, so I assume it's a server-based problem. But I have no idea what can cause that. Any ideas?

I'd be thankful for any tips.

Thanks in advance

EDIT

Because I forgot and this may be an important factor I also paste doctype declaration:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

EDIT 2

```
http://larte2002.vizz.pl/gosc/bl/cennik/ <- client's server, which shows textboxes

http://89.65.65.3/BL/cennik/ <- my server, checkboxes
```

Content on servers is exactly the same on both!

Comment: i paste this code in simple .html file and i show me checkbox .which server are you using?

Comment: Well, I don't honestly know, it's not mine server. I'll try to find out.

Comment: which browser you are using ?

Comment: Can you provide a test link, maybe publish a simple html or fiddle so it can be tested?

Comment: I've checked both Firefox (up-to-date) and Chrome.

I added to my question two links for testing. Sites on both servers are exactly the same.

Comment: I can access larte2002, but I'm getting a timeout error when trying to browse your server, so I cannot compare, but I see some checkboxes on the page (right next to a label "pomoc w założeniu działalności gospodarczej", for example). I see it's an Apache server, are you using any helper functions to generate HTML or it's just plain text?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp), for checkboxes the format is `input type="checkbox" name="boxname" value="boxval">Box text` , so it may be that you have the name before type instead of after. Maybe try switching that.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it makes no real difference, I've done this many times. Also I put exactly same file on a different server and it works just fine.