# Inserting checkbox into table produces textbox instead

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

I am using this code to add a checkbox to each row of a table. But, the checkbox shows up as a textbox with the `ClientID` in it:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
    $cid=$row['ClientID'];
    echo '<tr>
            <td>'.$row['ClientID'].'</td>
            <td><input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"checkbox'.$cid.'\" value='.$cid.'></td>
            <td>'.$row['FirstName'].'</td>
            <td>'.$row['LastName'].'</td>
            <td>'.$row['Email'].'</td>
            <td>'.$row['KDWP_Nbr'].'</td>
            <td>'. date('F d, Y', strtotime($row['DOB'])) . '</td>
            <td>'.$row['DriverLicenseNbr'].'</td>
            <td>'.$row['PrimaryPhone'].'</td>
            <td>'.$row['SecondaryPhone'].'</td>
            <td>'.$row['Address1'].'</td>
            <td>'.$row['Address2'].'</td>
            <td>'.$row['City'].'</td>
            <td>'.$row['State'].'</td>
            <td>'.$row['ZipCode'].'</td>
            <td>'.$row['ClientNotes'].'</td>
        </tr>';
```

Why wouldn't it show up as a checkbox?

Comment: Since your echo begins with `'` you don't need to escape your `"` (double-quotes).

Comment: Don't escape double quotes.  To verify. Check your source of your Php page,  youll see

Comment: I just ran it on phptester.net and it is a checkbox.  This question can not be replicated and will be closed.  Please edit you answer asap.

Comment: Really? Someone upvoted this question?  Delete this useless question already.

Comment: Duplicate Question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18718724/textbox-displayed-instead-of-checkbox

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read if a checkbox is checked in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4554758/how-to-read-if-a-checkbox-is-checked-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

Remove slash

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox'.$cid.'" value="'.$cid.'">
```